# How do I validate the signature of the netbeans download (zip) file. I HAVE the asc keyfile

Tags: netbeans, gnupg, pgp

Cannot verify signature of NetBeans installer

**I am using Windows 10 Pro build 17134.648**.
Downloaded **incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin.zip** from https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans/incubating-11.0/incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin.zip.

Installed & verified Kleopatra+gpg4Win.

Tried to use Kleopatra to verify the NetBeans zip file. K error message was: **"failed to find encrypted/signed data"**.

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Update your question with all of the following: [1] Your operating system. [2] A link to the page you used to download NetBeans, and details of the specific file you downloaded. [3] The output of the failed validation.

Comment: I have added the requested information via edit.